# Failed to link to module 'rlm_python': rlm_python.so

Tags: freeradius

I was trying to create a python authentication for freeradius 3.0.8. I followed [this example](https://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_python). But when I'm trying to start freeradius in debug mode using command `radiusd -X` It shows following error.

```
/usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/python[9]: Failed to link to module 'rlm_python': rlm_python.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked /usr/local/lib/ folder and found that rlm_python module is not there. How can I add that module? My python module inside `/raddb/mods-available/` is as follows.

```
  python {
  module = example

  mod_authorize = ${.module}
  func_authorize = authorize
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rlm_python isn't always packaged depending on the distribution.

Basic build instructions can be found here: http://wiki.freeradius.org/building/Home

You will also need to have installed the python-dev/python-devel package on your system.  If python still doesn't work you may need to specify the path to the python binary manually by passing it to configure e.g. `./configure --with-rlm-python-bin=/usr/bin/python2.7`.

If you just wan to verify the configure scripts have picked up python `cd src/modules/rlm_python; ./configure`

On my system (macOS 10.11.6) the output when python is found is:

```
checking for gcc... /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -E
checking for python2.7... python2.7
configure: Python sys.prefix "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7"
configure: Python sys.exec_prefix "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7"
configure: Python sys.version "2.7"
configure: Python local_mod_libs ""
configure: Python base_mod_libs ""
configure: Python other_libs "-u _PyMac_Error $(PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR)/Versions/$(VERSION)/$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK) -ldl -framework CoreFoundation"
checking for Python.h in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/... yes
checking for Py_Initialize in -lpython2.7 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating all.mk
```

Once the configure script find the python binary, it'll generally all "just work", as it can then get compilation and linking flags from python itself.

Comment: What exactly do I need to do to package rlm_python?

Comment: What packaging system are you using?

Comment: I'm using following commands to build freeradius 
`./configure  
make`, Sorry if that is not what you are asking. I'm new to freeradius

Comment: Expanded the answer