# Failed to link Rlm_python.so

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, freeradius

I am using freeradius 3.0.13 and trying to create a python module. i am following this link [rlm_python](https://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_python%60) to authenticate with freeradius. but when i start freeradius in debug mode some error occurred relating to python.

by entering command radiusd -X this error occurs:

> /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/python[10]: Failed to link to module 'rlm_python': /usr/lib64/freeradius/rlm_python.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

i followed this stack overflow answer [rlm_python.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371531/failed-to-link-to-module-rlm-python-rlm-python-so/45375703#45375703) 
but didn't resolved my issue and still same issue. i am new to freeradius, so what is correct way to include all python packages to link python module. In mods-available/python, i tried with three different paths but same issue.

> python_path = ${modconfdir}/${.:name}
>
> python_path= "/etc/raddb/mods-config/python/"
>
> python_path= "/etc/raddb/mods-config/python/:/usr/lib64/python2.7

where i am doing wrong and what is correct way to link python module with freeradius ?

.

Comment: Have you installed the freeradius-python package?  Did you build the FreeRADIUS source with the python development headers present?